# Is there a shorthand way to check for a null to avoid a null reference exception?

Tags: c#

I have this code that first checks to see if an object is null like this: `this.ButtonLabel.Text != null`

```
    private async void ChangeTheColours(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.ButtonLabel.Text != null && 
               (string)this.ButtonLabel.Text.Substring(0, 1) != " ")
            {
                ConfigureColors((Button)sender, "C");
                await Task.Delay(200);
                ConfigureColors((Button)sender, State);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex,
                new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        {"ChangeTheColours", "Exception"},
                        {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
                });
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can clean up this checking of null and just return from the function later than using the if block and doing the initial `this.ButtonLabel.Text` check ?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Comment: `Substring` returns a *string* so there's no reason to cast.

Comment: Is `this.ButtonLabel.Text?.StartsWith(" ") == false` a C# thing that works? Probably a better way to write the `== false` part at the very least.

Comment: @Ry- not like that, as `?.` will return `null` if `Text` is null and the check becomes `null == false`.

Comment: (And is it actually possible for the `Text` property of whatever it is to be `null`? Seems weird.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: So `null == false` is true in C#? (Or does it not compile?)

Comment: @Ry- even if it was (it isn't), that's not the kind of condition you'd want in production code

Comment: @John: I’m assuming `!= true` is just `!`, right? My intention with `== false` is to map false to true, true to false, and null to false.

Comment: @Ry- what does work is the pattern-mathing `is`: if(ButtonLabel.Text?[0] is char x && x!=' '){...}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Does that cause an index out of bounds on a non-null empty string, or does the pattern matching do magic to stop that? I haven’t used C# in a while and can’t check yet, sorry :P

Comment: @John that already proves this is a bad idea. If you try this in Linqpad you'll see that the expression fails either for `null` or the space character, one way or the other

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah I think I misunderstood the logic. Either way, I do agree that it's not a good way to write it. If it's a common thing that OP needs to do and it isn't satisfied by `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` then they'd be better off writing an extension method IMHO.

Comment: @Ry- it does. There's no real point to null checks though. This is an XY question. I suspect the *real* question is: `How can I check whether a string isn't initialized?` in which case the answer is `String.IsNullOrWhitespace`. If the OP really wants to match non-empty strings where only the first character is a space, `IsNullOrEmpty` and a character check. The rest is language quizzes

Comment: @John and better for any maintainer, including the OP one month later. Now, let me try to get a one-liner switch expression .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the cleaner code you are looking for:

```
private async void ChangeTheColours(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ButtonLabel.Text))
         return;

    try
    {
        ConfigureColors((Button)sender, "C");
        await Task.Delay(200);
        ConfigureColors((Button)sender, State);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex,
            new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {"ChangeTheColours", "Exception"},
                    {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
            });
    }
}
```

If you only need to check for `null` (and not whitespaces) and you are using the object right away, you can use [Safe navigation operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/):

instead of

```
if(article != null && article.Author != null 
     && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(article.Author.Name)){ }
```

write:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(article?.Author?.Name)){  }
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `!`.

Comment: can you say where the ! is missing?

Comment: @Alan2 I think the last two code blocks show reversed logic with regards to the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` call.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs - For this example, would it be even safer to use: if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this?.ButtonLabel?.Text))